# Sample app using Ember Data and Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

Any sample app using ember data to recommend ? Ideally with Rails backend and models associations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using this app to follow as an example:
https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example

This blog post also has good direction:
[Getting started with Ember Data and Rails](http://timpark.io/2012/04/11/getting-started-with-ember-data-and-rails/)

I was able to understand associations by looking at the Ember-Data project's [documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/README.md) and [tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration):

Comment: The first link is broken now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code very useful. Very well fragmented into individual files and a nicely written router.
Exactly mirroring the CRUD behavior.

https://github.com/bazzel/ember-sample2

Answer (score 0):

Slightly outdated and simplistic, but I'll update this to revision 10 soon:

http://github.com/mehulkar/teams